# Intergrating the quantum field on a surface with respect to the full quantum field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, vector-fields

The quantum field $\phi(x^\mu)$ or $\phi(x^0,x^1, \dots, x^{d-1})$ exists only for $x^{d-1}\geq 0$. We are in Euclidean signature $g_{\mu\nu}=\delta_{\mu\nu}$. Let $\phi(x^0,x^1, \dots, x^{d-2}, 0)=\phi(\vec{y},0)$. How can we do the following path integral?

$$\int [\mathrm{d}\phi]exp[-\int (a\phi(\vec{y},0)^2+b(\phi(\vec{y},0)^2)^2)d^{d-1}y]$$

Here $\vec{y}$ is a coordinate describing points on the surface $x^{d-1}=0$. How can we do the above integral? If $\phi(\vec{y},0)$ is replaced with $\phi(x^\mu)$, then I know how to do it. Here I am writing it as $(\phi(\vec{y},0)^2)^2$ instead of  $\phi(\vec{y},0)^4$ because $\phi$ is a vector field.

What I actually want to calculate is of the form
$$\int [\mathrm{d}\phi]exp[-\int (a\phi(\vec{y},0)^2+b(\phi(\vec{y},0)^2)^2)d^{d-1}y-\int (c\phi(x^\mu)^2+d(\phi(x^\mu)^2)^2)d^{d}x]$$

But the normal $\phi$ terms can be integrated since if we introduce an auxiliary field, the second term just becomes a Gaussian integral. The terms on the surface ($\phi(\vec{y},0)$ terms) are nontrivial.

Comment: How do you justify your first statement? I sounds like a violation of some conservation principles.

Comment: @flippiefanus what do you mean? You can assume that $x^{d-1}< 0$ doesn't exist.

Comment: What would be a physical example of such a case?

Comment: @flippiefanus in the model I am considering there is a boundary field at $x^{d-1}=0$ that couples to $\phi(\vec{y},0)$.